# ADC wire is picking up noise from cellular antenna [EMC]

Tags: noise, antenna, emc, shielding

I have a 5 wire micro jst cable with a line for ADC readings from an IR sensor that is picking up interference from the cellular antenna of the microcontroller. Will I be able to reduce this noise if I use a USB cable with grounded shielding? What is the best way I can reduce this interference noise?

Thank you!

Comment: Trial and error is the only approach that the limited content of your question allows me to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNL2LE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>